# What do language do I need to learn for Unity

Tags: unity

Hi what language do I need to learn to start programming in unity? Can I learn it on code academy?

Comment: C#. Code Academy says they teach it, which makes sense, it's a major language.

Comment: Downvoted due to lack of research effort.

Comment: I have to agree with disc_code22 that this question does not demonstrate research effort. A good habit is to type your question into your search engine of choice first, before posting here. Especially for a popular engine like Unity, you'll tend to find lots of existing answers and even whole tutorial series or sample projects to get you started.

Comment: Ok I'm new here sorry

Comment: No worries - downvotes aren't the end of the world. Please visit the [help] and take our [intro tour](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour) to get acquainted with how this site works. If you stick with it, you'll be sharing high-quality, upvoted questions and answers in no time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unity scripts use C#.

There are courses available to learn C# on nearly every major code learning platform, including code academy.

Comment: Is it a modified  version or just regular?

Comment: @KyranClancy Unity has its own API that you'll be interfacing with, but the C# language itself is standard .NET 2.0 or 4.x, depending on the profile you select for your project.